# Is there function that can return products with different count?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

```
SKU COUNT
A   2
A   2
A   2
B   2
B   1
C   3
C   3
C   3
```

i Want to return SKU which have different counts

THIS IS FOR SQL query for oracle  data base

```
Return SKU COUNT
       B   2 
       B   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select sku, count(distinct count)
from my_table 
group by sku 
having count(distinct count) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple method uses `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.sku = t.sku and t2.count <> t.count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery to find the skus. For example:

```
select * 
from t
where sku in (select sku from t group by sku having min(count) <> max(count))
```

Answer (score 0):

you could tray using count(distinct count)

```
 select sku, count, count(distinct count)
 from my_table 
 group by  sku, count 
 having count(distinct count) > 1
```